# NoneType Error, Python

Tags: python, return, iterable, nonetype

I'm getting

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

on this line:

```
temp, function = findNext(function)
```

and have no idea why this is failing. I am using function in while loops:

```
while 0 < len(function):
    …
```

but am not iterating through it. All of the returns in `findNext(function)` are pretty much

```
return 'somestring',function[1:]
```

and cannot understand why it thinks I'm iterating on one of those objects.

Comment: It was kind of hard to make sense of your question because you gave such small snips of code. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that `findNext` falls off the end without returning anything, which makes it automatically return `None`.  Kind of like this:

```
>>> def findNext(function):
...     if function == 'y':
...         return 'somestring',function[1:]
...
>>> function = 'x'
>>> print(findNext(function))
None
>>> temp, function = findNext(function)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The solution would be to always return something.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! I had forgotten to put a catch all return at the end!

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
return 'somestring',function[1:]
```

is actually returning a tuple of length 2 and tuples are iterables. It would be more idiomatic to write that statement as:

```
return ('somestring', function[1:])
```

which makes its tuple nature far more obvious.

Comment: Okay, I had already changed that in my code, but how then can i get the tuple to combine with the variables it returns to? Do i have to say temp = tuple[0] \n function = tuple[1]?

Comment: I don't understand that question. You are doing "tuple unpacking" properly in the line `temp, function = findNext(function)` but I'm guessing that you are not unpacking consistently. It is hard to tell with the small bits of code you gave.

Comment: Sorry I am avoiding pasting the whole thing in, because it has a lot of repetitive if statements, but I can assure you that the unpacking is consistent. You got the question right, I was asking about unpacking. When it didn't work the first thing I looked for was consistency in the packing and unpacking. Thank you very much for the help.